# How to first combine properties of an object then remove the duplicates in an array of objects using Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects here:

```
const arr = [
  { id: 1, name: "test1", quantity:1 },
  { id: 2, name: "test2", quantity:1 },
  { id: 2, name: "test3", quantity:1 },
  { id: 3, name: "test4", quantity:1 },
  { id: 4, name: "test5", quantity:1 },
  { id: 5, name: "test6", quantity:1 },
  { id: 5, name: "test7", quantity:1 },
  { id: 6, name: "test8", quantity:1 }
];
```

I want to add quantities of the duplicate objects together before removing them

So the result is:

```
const arr = [
  { id: 1, name: "test1", quantity:1 },
  { id: 2, name: "test3", quantity:2 },
  { id: 3, name: "test4", quantity:1 },
  { id: 4, name: "test5", quantity:1 },
  { id: 5, name: "test6", quantity:2 },
  { id: 6, name: "test8", quantity:1 }
];
```

I have seen variations of it done removing duplicates using map or reduce but I haven't seen anything that can what I want to accomplish in an eloquent way without using too many loops.

I have been thinking about how to best accomplish this all day and haven't found anything, any help would be appreciated

Comment: What have you attempted?

Comment: `var unique = [...new Set(arr.map(({id}) => id))].map(e => arr.find(({id}) => id == e)); 

console.log(unique)
`  But that only removes duplicates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use reduce with an object to store the element with each id.

```js
const arr = [
  { id: 1, name: "test1", quantity:1 },
  { id: 2, name: "test2", quantity:1 },
  { id: 2, name: "test3", quantity:1 },
  { id: 3, name: "test4", quantity:1 },
  { id: 4, name: "test5", quantity:1 },
  { id: 5, name: "test6", quantity:1 },
  { id: 5, name: "test7", quantity:1 },
  { id: 6, name: "test8", quantity:1 }
];
const res = Object.values(
  arr.reduce((acc,curr)=>{
  acc[curr.id] = acc[curr.id] || {...curr, quantity: 0};
  acc[curr.id].quantity += curr.quantity;
  return acc;
  }, {})
);
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Small improvement by replacing `{quantity: 0}` with `{...curr, quantity: 0}` and then you can remove the line with the `name` assignment. With this minor update you can keep the same shape of the original objects, including the `id` attribute.

Comment: @Pablo Good suggestion.

Comment: That is really cool, I knew the path resided in reduce most likely, but I was using all kinds of loops in between, this is awesome, thanks :)

Comment: @VeironiOttan No problem.

Comment: Thanks just did, I was wondering what does this do precisely: ```acc[curr.id] = acc[curr.id] || {...curr, quantity: 0}; ```. In the code @hev1

Answer (score 0):

```js
const arr = [
    { id: 1, name: "test1", quantity: 1 },
    { id: 2, name: "test2", quantity: 1 },
    { id: 2, name: "test3", quantity: 1 },
    { id: 3, name: "test4", quantity: 1 },
    { id: 4, name: "test5", quantity: 1 },
    { id: 5, name: "test6", quantity: 1 },
    { id: 5, name: "test7", quantity: 1 },
    { id: 6, name: "test8", quantity: 1 }
];

var result = arr.reduce(function (r, a) {
    r[a.id] = r[a.id] || { id: a.id, quantity: 0, name: a.name };
    r[a.id].quantity += a.quantity;
    return r;
}, Object.create(null));

console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `forEach` loop and build object with aggregated quantity count.

```js
const convert = (arr) => {
  const res = {};
  arr.forEach(({ id, ...rest }) =>
    res[id] ? (res[id].quantity += 1) : (res[id] = { id, ...rest })
  );
  return Object.values(res);
};

const arr = [
  { id: 1, name: "test1", quantity: 1 },
  { id: 2, name: "test2", quantity: 1 },
  { id: 2, name: "test3", quantity: 1 },
  { id: 3, name: "test4", quantity: 1 },
  { id: 4, name: "test5", quantity: 1 },
  { id: 5, name: "test6", quantity: 1 },
  { id: 5, name: "test7", quantity: 1 },
  { id: 6, name: "test8", quantity: 1 },
];

console.log(convert(arr));
```